# Objective-C iOS app crashes during CFStringAppend for unknown reason

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

In my iPhone app, for some users the app will always crash, whenever they open a certain window. The same window works fine for me and other people, but always causes a crash for some people. It is unclear at this moment what the difference is between people for whom it fails, and for whom it works fine.

The animation to open the specific view will run fine, but will then cause a crash immediately after the animation is finished.

They have sent me the crashlog, but it is hard to understand what is exactly going wrong. I am hoping you can help me understand. The cause for the failure as given by the crashlog is the following exception:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1836ffd38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x182c14528 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18370d1f8 -[NSObject+ 1372664 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139
3   UIKit                           0x18cec7cc4 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1837056e4 ___forwarding___ + 1379
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1835eb0dc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 91
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1835d6be8 CFStringAppend + 519
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1836bddf0 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9271
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1836bf658 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 131
9   AccessibilityUtilities          0x192d6b388 _AXStringForArgs + 279
10  UIKit                           0x1a242adf8 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility viewDidAppear:] + 267
11  UIKit                           0x18cb2869c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 851
12  UIKit                           0x18cb28c08 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 227
13  UIKit                           0x18cbcee00 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1327
14  UIKit                           0x1a2440cd4 -[UINavigationControllerAccessibility navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 111
15  UIKit                           0x18cc96bbc __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 251
16  UIKit                           0x18cc229d8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 115
17  UIKit                           0x18cd67d30 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke.124 + 751
18  UIKit                           0x18cb47d7c -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 763
19  UIKit                           0x18cb4770c -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 311
20  UIKit                           0x18cb47418 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 295
21  UIKit                           0x1a2468970 -[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility animationDidStop:finished:] + 131
22  QuartzCore                      0x1876ebd6c CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks+ 1232236 (void*) + 283
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x183085048 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x183091b74 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1015
25  CoreFoundation                  0x1836a7f20 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 11
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1836a5afc __CFRunLoopRun + 2011
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1835c62d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
28  GraphicsServices                0x185457f84 GSEventRunModal + 99
29  UIKit                           0x18cb73880 UIApplicationMain + 207
30  Flyskyhy                        0x10490bd80 main + 32128 (main.m:17)
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x1830ea56c start + 3
```

The crashlog seems to indicate that it goes wrong while doing a `CFStringAppend`, but it is not clear which string is the problem, or what is wrong with it, or even why a `CFStringAppend` is needed. All strings visible in the view have been filled in already before the animation starts, and they all are correct.

EDIT:

As requested, here is the code that starts the view. Everything is under a NavigationController, so the new view controller is pushed on the navigation stack to open it.

```
WaypointEditController *controller = [[WaypointEditController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WayPointEdit" bundle:nil];
controller.navigationItem.title = @"New Waypoint";
// initialisation of other, custom, fields of controller

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The `WaypointEditController` class that is pushed is derived from `UIViewController`. The `viewWillAppear` is overridden, to do initialisation of the fields of the view. But - relevant here - `viewDidAppear` is **not** overridden.

In case relevant, here are the most important actions in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"New Waypoint";

    // other initialisation of internal fields
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing the crash? It’s hard to diagnose the issue based only on the above.

Comment: As you can see above, no code of the app is involved in the exception.

Comment: Looking at the above it looks like you are getting an Unrecognised Selector exception somewhere inside the ViewDidAppear. I would double check that code or post it here so I can check it.

Comment: The UIViewControllerAccessibility that does the viewDidAppear, is part of Apple iOS, so I don't have the code for that. As you can see from the trace, no code of my app is involved at all in the exception (except for the standard main function).

Comment: I wonder if the involvement of the UIViewControllerAccessibility and AccessibilityUtilities indicate that the users have some form of accessibility switched on. I have asked them, but they say no.

Comment: If you post the code that presents the window that crashes as well as the controller code for that window it will help... Although it's an IOS lib that is crashing it would be because there is a mistake somewhere earlier in the code or maybe incorrect usage. Without seeing any of that code it's impossible to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157668/discussion-between-thomas-maw-and-fishinear).

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the original poster. Still researching.

Comment: @ThomasMaw I have added relevant source code now. Sorry for the delay I have been ill.

Comment: @mamills If you see it happening while running with XCode, please try to change things in the view or viewcontroller to see what makes the problem go away. I have no possibility to experiment, because everything works fine for me in the lab; I just have customers who reported the problem. Also feel free to edit the question if you have more background info for your case.

Comment: @fishinear - Like you, I have customers reporting this problem and I could see the stack traces that XCode downloads from production but I could not reproduce it... until I tried enabling "voice over". The other accessibility options that I tried worked OK. The stack trace shows that iOS is sending a selector of "length" to an instance of UILabel (??) So I tried adding a "length" to UILabel to get past this problem but then it just failed with an unknown selector of _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString. No workaround yet. Still researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you, I have customers reporting this problem and I could see the stack traces that XCode downloaded from production but I could not reproduce it... until I tried enabling "voice over".

The other accessibility options that I tried worked OK.

The stack trace shows that iOS is sending a selector of "length" to an instance of UILabel. This seemed odd. To see what would happen, I added a "length" method to UILabel to return the length of the UILabel's text property. Then it just failed with an unknown selector of _encodingCantBeStoredInEightBitCFString. So clearly iOS thought that my UILabel was something that it wasn't.

This ended up being because "description" was used for the name of my UILabel property/IBOutlet.

To fix the problem I renamed the property from "description" to something different. I suspect that my synthesized "description" getter was overriding NSObject's description method (which returns an NSString which fits the selectors which were being sent to my UILabel).

Comment: Brilliant! I have an IBOutlet called "description" as well in the relevant view controller, so it is likely the same cause. I did not even know that NSObject had a description method. Now I just need to find a way to trigger the problem. Switching "voice over" on does not work, because then the app becomes totally unusable...